# How to use prepared list of words inside the swift project to randomly display those words?

Tags: ios, swift

I need to recreate Alias game. It's all good except I have no idea how to do this one part. So I have a file with 500-700 words and I want to display this words on the VC one by one randomly when I press a button "Next". But I don't know how to access this file from my PC inside the code. Could you please suggest any solution that could be used, maybe there is a solution using firebase. Anyways hoping someone could help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the file menu in modern Xcode, there's an option called "Add files to ...". Use that to add your text file.

While running, get the file from the app bundle using:

```
Bundle.main.url(forResource: "the_file_you_added", withExtension: "txt")
```

Get the file contents with `String(contentsOf: fileURL)`, and parse the file contents with `components(separatedBy: ", ")`

500-700 names is small enough to keep in memory as an array. To select randomly from an array (without duplicates), first `shuffle()` the array.

Comment: Array has a shuffle method.

Comment: @matt - the swift shuffle method is the first thing mentioned in the link I included. Edited to remove the link and mention shuffle inline, and to not commit to an approach nested conditionals.

Answer (score -1):

I join the answer from [@dahn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/294949/danh)

> if let fileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "the_file_you_added",
> withExtension: "txt") {
> if let fileContents = try? String(contentsOf: fileURL) {
> // parse the fileContents, probably with components(separatedBy: ", ")
> }
> }

, but I will add that a random element can be obtained as follows:

```
array.randomElement()
```